# PHP json encode and decode

Tags: php, json

I'm new to json. I have existing json data in a file. here it looks like:

```
{

    "qwqw":{
        "id":3,
        "item1":{
            "id":15,
            "price":31.85
        },
        "item2":{
            "id":17,
            "price":26
        },
        "item3":{
            "id":16,
            "price":57.85
        }
    }
}
```

I can get this value using json_decode. I will add another entry using this code.

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('test.ini'), true );
$data[] = array(
                    'id'=>4,
                    'item1'=>array(
                        'id'=>15,
                        'price'=>11
                    ), 
                    'item2'=>array(
                        'id'=>17,
                        'price'=>12
                    ),
                    'item3'=>array(
                        'id'=>16,
                        'price'=>13.50
                    )
                );

file_put_contents('test.ini', json_encode($data) );
```

This works properply. When I decoded it again. this how it looks.

```
     {

        "qwqw":{
            "id":3,
            "item1":{
                "id":15,
                "price":31.85
            },
            "item2":{
                "id":17,
                "price":26
            },
            "item3":{
                "id":16,
                "price":57.85
            }
        },

         "0":{
            "id":3,
            "item1":{
                "id":15,
                "price":11
            },
            "item2":{
                "id":17,
                "price":12
            },
            "item3":{
                "id":16,
                "price":13.5
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is, can I change the value "0" ? to a string.

anyone who can help ?

Comment: Just use $data["the_string_you_want"] = array(...);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is a string here, you can tell because it has quotes around it.

But if you want a different string, don't use:

```
$data[] = array(
   /* ... */
)
```

but:

```
$data['myKey'] = array(
   /* ... */
)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can

```
$data['string'] = array(
                    'id'=>4,
                    'item1'=>array(
                        'id'=>15,
                        'price'=>11
                    ), 
                    'item2'=>array(
                        'id'=>17,
                        'price'=>12
                    ),
                    'item3'=>array(
                        'id'=>16,
                        'price'=>13.50
                    )
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$data["the_string_key"] = array(
   //...
);
```